# What does 踏踏实实 mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does this actress mean here with "踏踏实实"？

Maybe, she hopes the roles are "completely" (separated)

演员永远躲在角色后面。我希望我塑造的角色一个是一个，而且互不重复，踏踏实实。

Comment: Did you try 踏踏实实 in Google Translate?

Comment: This is an advice which many Chinese mothers used to give their children, especially their sons. I got one from mine.

Comment: @TangHo  I believe OP knows what 踏踏实实 means on its own. It is not a difficult phrase. It is the contextual meaning that he is looking for?

Answer (score 3):

The actress means she wants every role she plays to be a unique one and each displays a different aspect. 踏踏实实 is used here to express she wants to build a firm foundation for her acting career ***by being successful for one character and then for the next one***.  So, in the end, there isn't a character that would be poorly played by her.

Comment: Thanks, I just can't get the meaning from 踏踏实实

Answer (score 1):

The whole sentence can be simplified as "我希望踏踏实实的去塑造角色, 一个角色是一个角色" - She wants to put up her best/real effort to interpret the character she is playing truthfully, each character each time. 踏踏实实 - footing solidly on the ground, can be seen as the "best/real effort to be truthfully...".

踏踏实实的作事 - put up real effort for work.

踏踏实实的作人 - put up effort to be a good person.

**Edit:**

After further thought, I feel the speaker lacks the ability to express her thought clearly but tried very hard to make a classy saying with the addition of a few unnecessary/inappropriate idioms that create confusion. (嚼文嚼字亂用成語的結果是不知所云 :)

[image]

塑造的角色 – interpret the role in the play

一个是一个 – true to the charter of the role (in the story)

互不重复 – one not to repeat another (does not fit the sentence, should be eliminated, or change to 互為一體 – one (me) exactly  like the other (role played))

踏踏实实 – (should be changed to 真真实实 or 真真切切 to mean) remain truthful to the role

Now let's put all together:

**我希望我塑造的角色 一个是一个， 互為一體 ，真真实实(切切)**

**I wish I interpret the role in the play is true to the charter of the role in the story，as I and the role become one person，to remain truthful to the role I play.**

Although the sentence remains not well constructed, but understandable. Hopefully.

Comment: I'm wondering what other phrase could be used to replace 踏踏实实 here, because somehow I can't wrap my head around this usage.

Comment: I think "实实在在" is the equivalent of 踏踏实实 in this case. However, I do have difficulty understanding the exact message she expresses in this sentence. I'll get back to you if the meaning isn't what I've explained.

Comment: While 踏踏实实 means put up an effort (实实) step by step (踏踏), it also has the implication that encourages people "not to fail/make mistakes by the lack of effort".

Comment: Actually the sentence in question works just fine without the 踏踏实实 which could be considered superfluous as it serves no useful purpose, grammatically or semantically. Hence not surprising about the difficulty of "wrap my head around this usage" It's like saying "If you got to go, you got to go; go man go"

Answer (score 1):

It means 'solid', 互不重复，踏踏实实 are in parallel relationship. 互补重复 modifies characters, so 踏踏实实 also modifies characters, he want his characters are strong and solid.